# How to break long line of xml files only on display not in the actual code

Tags: formatting, wrapping

I have an xml file with some text which is so long, that it does not fit into the normal line of my editor.

Is there an xml-specific way to insert a newline just for formatting, i.e. ignored by a correct xml parser?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for exists. **Standard** XML does not contain a built in way to describe its own representation. Unless extended to do so (kinda like html... kinda). Seeing as this site is for VI and VIM you will get editor specific answers to this question, therefore you may have a better chance of getting what you want out of this question by re-asking it on stack overflow. Otherwise if using vim Statox's answer is correct way of doing what you ask in the VI and VIM editors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appeared that OP isn't looking for a solution in vim but a generic solution to modify an XML file which makes this question off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`:h 'wrap'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wrap%27):

> This option changes how text is displayed.  It doesn't change the text
>   in the buffer, see ['textwidth'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27) for that.
>
> When on, lines longer than the width of the window will wrap and
>   displaying continues on the next line.  When off lines will not wrap
>   and only part of long lines will be displayed.  When the cursor is
>   moved to a part that is not shown, the screen will scroll
>   horizontally.

Simply add this line to your vimrc:

```
set wrap
```

Or to use wrap only on xml buffers:

```
autocommand FileType xml setlocal wrap
```

(See [`:h :setlocal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Asetlocal))

Comment: hm,... i am not looking for a tool specific solutions for not displaying a newline or not.

Comment: @user2609605 Setting the `wrap` option will make long lines appears as several lines on your screen while keeping them as one line on the actual code, isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: To the light of @Archangel33 's comment I understand your comment now `i am not looking for a tool specific solutions` then indeed you're not on the right site.